# Number of multiples of 7 in a certain range with digit restrictions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find the amount of both positive and negative multiples of $7$ in the range of $(-4,000,000, 4,000,000)$ are there such that the only numbers that are used as digits are $4, 2,$ and $0.$ For example, one such number is $42=6 \cdot 7.$

I have not gotten much progress, but so far I realized that for the millions digit we can only have $2$ or $0.$ For all other digits we can have $4, 2,$ or $0.$ This gives $2 \cdot 3^6=1458$ possible numbers in the range of $[0, 4,000,000).$ We can later double the amount of numbers in this range then subtract $2$ (since we don't count $0$) for our desired outcome. However, I'm not sure how to compute how many of these $1458$ possible numbers are multiples of $7$ other than a large, messy casework bash. Can I have some help?

Edit: I still have not gotten much progress. I do understand how we may divide by 7 to get an estimation of $208$ for half the interval, but I am wondering if there is a way to rigorously show that this is indeed the correct amount of possible numbers instead of an estimation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might guess without much justification that it could be about $1458/7 \approx 208.29$ (for the positive cases) and indeed it is

Comment: @Henry How would we guess that around a seventh of the numbers in that form are a multiple of $7?$ Also, is there a more rigorous way to compute it other than approximation?

Comment: The guess is simply that about a seventh of positive integers up to a limit are divisible by $7$ and so about a seventh of of a particular subset might also be.  But this may be wrong either because the subset is extra special (suppose we were restricted to digits $0$ and $7$) or because this is only an approximation

Comment: Oh I see. It seems that for our case the guess results with the correct amount. Do you think there a more rigorous, but not very messy strategy to doing this?

Comment: Ask the same question for a modified base 3

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by a "modified base". Do you mean I should ask the same question except instead of base $10$ it's in base $3?$

Comment: Well all all powers of $10$ are congruent to the powers of $3$ modulo $7$ ... But $4$ isn't typically a digit in base $3$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Well I see that $10^0 \equiv 3^0=1 \mod 7, 10^1 \equiv 3^1 = 3 \mod 7, 10^2 \equiv 3^2 = 2 \mod 7.$ We get a cycle of $1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5 \pmod{7}.$ We never seem to attain $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we find  the greatest $7$-multiple under $8$ million. The we factor it's cofactor of $7$. Then we express the result as sums, products, or differences of powers of $2$.
$$
4,000,000-(-4,000,000)\\
=8,000,000\\
=1+7,999,999\\
=1+7(1,142,857)\\
=1+7({199\cdot 5743})
$$

\begin{align*}
1&=2^0\\
7&=4+2+1\\
&=4+2+2^0\\
199&=128\quad\space\space+64\quad\space+7\\
&=2^{(4+2+2^0)}+2^{(4+2)}+(4+2+2^0)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
5743&=4096\quad+1024\quad+512\quad+128\quad-16\quad-1
\\&=2^{(2(4)+4)}+2^{(2(4)+2)}+2^{(2(4)+1)}
+2^{(2(4)+4)}-2^{2(4)}-2^0
\end{align*}

If we now "write" the [binary] expression for the product of $199$ and $5743$ we should have the desired result..

Comment: Is there a process on how you factored $1,142,857?$ Also is there motivation behind expressing the results as sums, products, or diferences of power of $2?$ Also, I'm a little confused on what you mean by the [binary] expression.

Comment: @mathisfun
   Wolfram Alpha factored $1,142,857$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1142857).   
 I expressed the results in terms of powers of  $2$ because the only digits allowed were $4,\space 2,\space 0.\space$ By binary expression, I mean the collection of terms that are powers of $2$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks very much. I will ask you any questions if I am still confused :)

Comment: @mathisfun
 I think you will love Wolfram Alpha as is can do almost anything mathematical (like factoring or expanding or solving  polynomial expressions) and many non-mathematical things you can imagine.

Comment: Oh ok! I'll check it out. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: By the way, what if we had numbers that added up greater than $7.$ For example, if we only wanted digits $6,3,0.$ Since $3+6=9,$ we can't proceed with this strategy?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not very sure when you say "if we now "write" the [binary] expression for the product of $199$ and $5743$ we should have the desired result." I'm not seeing how multiplying the two numbers in their "binary" forms, $2^{(4+2+2^0)}+2^{(4+2)}+(4+2+2^0)$ and $2^{(2(4)+4)}+2^{(2(4)+2)}+2^{(2(4)+1)}
+2^{(2(4)+4)}-2^{2(4)}-2^0$ changes anything.